# Use "locate" under some specific directory?

Tags: command-line, files

I was wondering how to restrict the search range of "locate" to some directory?

For example, how to find files/directories with string "math" in their names under some directory "/home/tim/science/"?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**UPDATE**: A note about using locate's **regex option** vs the shell's **[filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)** in relation to locate's args ...

**SHELL FILENAME EXPANSION**
When you type `locate /bin/b*` (note there are no quotes), several things happen.

1. First, *shell filename-expansion* will expand the special *shell pattern charecter* * (This is because the * is unprotected, ie. there are no "double-quotes")
2. This resulting expansion is a **list of filenames**. which is perhaps very long... This list is passed to `locate` as many individual commandline args.
3. `locate` then tests each of these args against each of the files in its database, and outputs matches.

Take note however, that 'locate' has no concept of the current working directory. It only matches your args against the *fully-qualified* file-names in its database.
This means that it will match both `/bin/bash` **and** `/home/user/bin/brackets`
You have some degree of control this way, but locate's *regex search* offers more; as do some other of locate's options.

**LOCATE'S REGEX OPTION**
When you type `locate -r "/bin/b.*"` different things happen than do with simple args.. (*shell-expanded-args*  are just a list of simple args)

1. The `-r` option tells *locate* to treat your arg as a regex pattern.
2. The quotation marks protect the * from shell filename-expansion. It means that the * and the dot . are now *special regex characters*
3. Being regex, you can very easily tell 'locate' to match its database entry in various ways: eg1. `locate -r "^/bin/b.*"` produces file names beginning with **/bin/b** ... eg2. `locate -r ~/"bin/b.*"` produces file names beginning with **/home/user/bin/b** .. Note that the ~/ is **not** protected by "quotation-marks" and is therefore subject to *shell tilde-expansion* which converts ~/ into /home/user/

Summary: "shell filname expansion" is quite different to 'regex'

Now back to the original post:

---

`locate` typically lists the entire database to stdout, so to limit it to a particular directory you need to filter it... You can do this via locate's options.

You can use locate's regex capability, rather than just shell-globbing  ...(`locate /dir/myfile*`  is shell-globbing)...

From *info locate*: `-r`,`--regex`

- "... (regex) matches are performed against the whole path name, and so by default a pathname will be matched if any part of it matches the specified regular expression.  The regular expression may use **^** or **$** to anchor a match at the beginning or end of a pathname."

note: -i = ignore case
. . . . . -r = regex
. . . . . ~/ will be expanded  by the shell to /home/user (when ~/ is not in quotes)
. . . . . **'\ '** (baskslash+space; no quotes) is a literal space (to avoid shell expansion). You can put the string in quotes, but be sure to leave the **~/** outside the quotes: `~/my\ regex` or `-/"my regex"`

eg. `locate -ir ~/".*"la\ bella\ vita` is the same as `locate -ir ~/".*la bella vita"` and will search your entire home directory for "La Bella Vita" occurring anywhere.

You can also limit the search to just the file **name** but using the `-b` or `--basename` .. in which case the regex start-of-line `^` applies to only the basename...

I most commonly find myself using `locate -bir`

PS.. `Locate` is so fast, that I have **never** used `find` ... nor have I used nautilus search (too slow)

With 'locate', if you are looking for something which is newly added, just run `sudo updatedb` to refresh locate's database... (but if you've newly added it, you probably know where it is :)....

Answer (score 17):

Pipe it through grep, like this

```
$ locate less | grep ^/bin
/bin/bzless
/bin/less
/bin/lessecho
/bin/lessfile
/bin/lesskey
/bin/lesspipe
/bin/zless
```

Edit: The other answer is better, I didn't know you can pass a pattern to locate.

Comment: @Adam.. Don't underestimate your method; it is quite okay, but you can use locate's own regex instead of piping to grep.. The "other" method you refer to does not use regex and behaves quite differently.... I've added some detail about the differences to my answer...

Comment: locate less | grep ^/bin is way faster than locate -r ^/bin/.*less, because locate less will perform an efficient search for the word less, and locate -r will perform a regex operation on all the entries in locatedb

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco What is "efficient search for the word" and why is it faster than regex?

Comment: @Flashrunner Because `locate` does an `O(log(n))` search over `locatedb` when you give it a non-regex search query, then you can use `grep`'s regex to perform an `O(m)` search over the already reduced sub-results. (n = total number of entries in `locatedb` [i.e. all of your drive's files], m = # of entries that match less in your `locatedb`), total running complexity: `O(log(n)) + O(m)`, where m is on average `log(n)`, so you get `2*O(log(n))`, as opposed to `O(n)` when you perform a regex query over all entries in `locatedb`.

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco But why non-regex search over db is `O(log(n))` while regex search is `O(n)`? Amount of entries in db is the same in each case. I guess it is search algorithm?

Comment: @Flashrunner Because regex is implemented using a state machine. For *each character in the input*, the state changes and a transition occurs in the state machine, hence O(n).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `locate /rootpath/*filenamespec`.I hadn't tried it before, but it appears to work. To do your example, it would be `locate /home/tim/science/*math*`

You may want to look at the `find` command rather than `locate` for that sort of behaviour. The syntax would be `find rootforsearch -name filenamepattern -print`. In this case, your example would require `find /home/tim/science -name *math* -print`.Not as fast as locate as there's no database to search ... it actually searches the filesystem. There are lots of options you can use other than print as well, if you intend to actually do something with the file.

Comment: This is the best answer as it uses `locate` itself (not requiring any other utility such as `grep`) and does without regexps (which are nice, but unnecessary in this case).

Comment: This one works really like  a charm that you can use locate to search files in specific directory Path, thanks @Nerdfest

Answer (score 4):

For me the most convenient is

```
cd /home/tim/science
locate math | grep `pwd`
```

Comment: Did you really read the question?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `locate --all` as in perhaps `locate -A tim science math`. I think that is in the spirit of simplicity of locate.