# Automated way to create a directory tree

Tags: command-line, directory

I am trying to make a directory tree from A to Z where the next directory is within the current directory.

For example: B is within A and C is within B and so on..

```
-A
--B
---C
----...Z
```

Any clues on how to get it done the automated way?

Comment: I wonder what’s the practical purpose of such directories. IMHO this looks more like a question for [codegolf.se].

Comment: @Melebius One possible purpose is to create a directory structure as a test case, in order to help verify that some other command, script, or application works property. Here's [a recent instance](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023244) where the question itself wasn't about creating specific directory structures, but knowing how to write commands to do so was useful for testing purposes, not in spite of how the specific structure was contrived and weird, but because of it. (We do also have many questions about creating specific directory structures, which can be found by searching for "`mkdir -p`".)

Answer (score 25):

With `mkdir`, `printf` and bash's brace expansion:

```
$ mkdir -p "$(printf "%s/" {A..Z})"
$ tree A
A
└── B
    └── C
        └── D
            └── E
                └── F
                    └── G
                        └── H
                            └── I
                                └── J
                                    └── K
                                        └── L
                                            └── M
                                                └── N
                                                    └── O
                                                        └── P
                                                            └── Q
                                                                └── R
                                                                    └── S
                                                                        └── T
                                                                            └── U
                                                                                └── V
                                                                                    └── W
                                                                                        └── X
                                                                                            └── Y
                                                                                                └── Z

25 directories, 0 files
```

- `{A..Z}` expands to `A B ... Z`,
- `printf "%s/"` prints the arguments with a `/` after them, so I get `A/B/...Z/`
- and `mkdir -p` creates the `A/B/.../Z` directory with any parent directories that needed creating.

Comment: thanks for that. Thought I get this error while . I use the command mkdir: A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W/X/Y: No such file or directory

Comment: @Nish There's a `-p` in the `mkdir` command.

Comment: my bad, i tried that on my mac instead of ubuntu.

And a follow up question is this-->  let's say I wanted to have A1..A100 directory within A (in the same structure AtoZ). Then B1..B100 within B. So it looks something like this --> imgur.com/jfuKEdf

Comment: Let's say you post a follow-up as an actual question instead of in the comments, and didn't use images but text. That would be much better, no?

Comment: I understand your point here. Its difficult to post it as its not a code and its a hugeass output at that. So simply looking at the screenshot makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Nish you can shorten the output by showing the beginning and the end only, right? And please, do not post screenshots or images of text, that's just... cruel. But useful images can be shown inline. And: Welcome at StackExchange!

Comment: It works in zsh just the same as in bash.

Comment: this was the simplest solution i could get!

Answer (score 7):

At the very simple level, you could make use of `{A..Z}` expansion to generate all the letter, then iteratively make and enter each one:

```
~/test_directory$ for d in {A..Z}; do mkdir "$d"; cd "$d"; done
~/test_directory/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W/X/Y/Z$
```

As you can see in my prompt output, now  you have completely chained directory.

However, if actual directory names are different than just alphabet, you'll have to somehow provide the list of directory names, perhaps via a file, over which you iterate and do same process again. Basically, this

```
while IFS= read -r dir_name;do mkdir "$dir_name"; cd "$dir_name" ;done < directory_list.txt
```

Comment: thats pretty cool. Here's a followup question. let's say I wanted to have A1..A100 directory within A (in the same structure AtoZ). Then B1..B100 within B. So it looks something like this --> https://imgur.com/jfuKEdf

Comment: @Nish ah, that'd require an inner loop so `for d in {A..Z}; do  mkdir "$d"; cd "$d";  for i in {1..100}; do  mkdir "${d}${i}"  ;done ;  done`

Comment: Or even without inner loop, `for d in {A..Z}; do mkdir "$d"; cd "$d"; mkdir "$d"{1..100}; done`

Comment: thanks for that. It seems to work but the order of the directory seem screwed up so 2 is not after 1. Its sorted randomly. Anyway to fix that? Here's a screenshot --> https://imgur.com/a/Zqj1c

Comment: @Nish Sorting order is text-based, not numerical as I think you expect.  As far as `tree`, I'm not sure how to fix that, but I think this might not even be `tree`'s problem, but rather shell's sorting order. I'd suggest asking actual question about that either here or better yet on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Nish, probably you are asking for a command as: `ls -1v --group-directories-first` or `ls -lv --group-directories-first`.

Answer (score 2):

Even though [muru's `printf` way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023522/22949) can't be beat, I personally like [**`jot`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/jot.1.html) for this sort of thing. `jot` isn't installed by default in Ubuntu. The [`athena-jot`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=athena-jot&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package provides it. Either of these commands works:

```bash
mkdir -p "$(jot -s/ -c 26 A)"
```

```bash
jot -s/ -c 26 A | xargs mkdir -p
```

Really any command that generates the sequence of letters and joins them with slashes will facilitate this, because its output can then be passed to `mkdir -p` either through [**command substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (as in [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023522/22949)) or using [**`xargs`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xargs.1.html). Here are some examples using a few tools and `xargs` that don't require that you install software, except perhaps on very minimal systems or Ubuntu Core:

```bash
perl -we 'print join "/", A..Z' | xargs mkdir -p
```

```bash
ruby -we 'print (?A..?Z).to_a * ?/' | xargs mkdir -p
```

```bash
python3 -c 'print("/".join(__import__("string").ascii_uppercase))' | xargs mkdir -p
```

Old Ubuntu releases come with Python 2 instead of Python 3. For that, just change `python3` to `python` to make that last command work, if you really want to do this with Python.

Similarly, [muru's short and simple way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023522/22949) can alternatively be written:

```
printf '%s/' {A..Z} | xargs mkdir -p
```

The trailing `/`, in the directory path `mkdir -p` is asked to create, is no problem and arguably is stylistically preferable. But it's fine to omit it, as the other examples in this answer do.